# How to tell the user the days he/she inputted is already reserved?

Tags: java, oop, time

I am currently practicing java.time and I ran into a reservation exercise.

How to tell that the days he/she inputted is already reserved?

```
LocalDate prevResdate;
LocalDate resDate;

    public Reserve(int ResDate)
{
     prevResdate=ResDate;
     resDate=ResDate;
}

if(prevResdate==resDate)
  System.out.println("Date already reserved!");
```

how to do it in a proper way?

Comment: I went to have a look the [JavaDocs for `LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) and found this statement - *"This is a value-based class; use of identity-sensitive operations (including reference equality (==), identity hash code, or synchronization) on instances of LocalDate may have unpredictable results and should be avoided. The equals method should be used for comparisons."* - So the answer is, you should use `equals`, which is pretty much the most appropriate place to start for most objects

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking and I suspect I'm not the only one. _"how to do it in a proper way?"_ could mean a number of things. Do you have some expected output/result that can be compared to what you're getting right now? Any error messages?

Comment: there is no error but the System.out.println("Date already reserved!"); did not display

Comment: [Comparing Objects](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Comparing_Objects)

Comment: How does the user input the date? As text? Why is `ResDate` and `int` and what does it signify? I would read your code more easily if you adhere to the Java naming conventions: methods and paramters have names that begin with a lowercase letter, so `reserve` and `resDate`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to do this :

```
public class Reserve {
    private LocalDate prevResdate;
    private LocalDate resDate;

    public Reserve(LocalDate ResDate) {
        this.prevResdate = ResDate;
        this.resDate = ResDate;
    }

    public LocalDate getResDate() {
        return resDate;
    }

    public void setResDate(LocalDate resDate) {
        if (prevResdate.compareTo(resDate) == 0)
            System.out.println("Date already reserved!");
        else
            this.resDate = resDate;
    }
}
```

Calling Code:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Reserve r = new Reserve(LocalDate.parse("2018-11-01"));

        r.setResDate(LocalDate.parse("2018-10-01"));

        System.out.println(r.getResDate());

    }

}
```

Comment: It will work, but `compareTo()` is not the best method for the purpose. `LocalDate` has methods `equals()` and `isEqual()` that lend themselves to more readable and natural code.